# How to insert data into foregin key column with JPA + Rest service

Tags: hibernate, rest, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have below table structure . Assume that all JPA annotations are used .

public class EntityA{

int id // PK 
.....
}

public class EntityB{

int id // PK 
.....
}

public class EntityC {

int id // PK

int someId // FK referes to EntityA id column .oneToOne mapping

int someId // FK referes to EntityB id column .oneToOne mapping

}

we have 3 different API to save the data into EntityA,B,C .

My question is .

1. is it right way of inserting the data when we have OneToOne mapping
2. when I m inserting data with separate API , foreign key table (column) is inserted with null value .

Can anyone tell me how  to insert data for foreign key table with separate API . ?

Comment: *is it right way of inserting the data when we have OneToOne mapping*. Is what the right way? You haven't posted any code so how can anyone answer if it is right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1) is it right way of inserting the data when we have OneToOne mapping ?

It depends on your requirement. But the whole thing can be achieved with single API instead of having three since it is any way one to one mapping. Get two JSON object and then you can split it up according to your table requirements and save it to database

2) when I am inserting data with separate API , foreign key table (column) is inserted with null value ?

No it is not supposed to be empty. If you are going to have three different API then the API which write to child table must provide information about parent table like primary key id (something to identify the parent table). If it is a single API this is going to simple any way